Using a 2D Lidar for 3D Navigation: Addressing Localization Drift in Open Spaces
I am working on a project where, due to budget constraints, we are using a 2D Lidar as a 3D Lidar by rotating it. We have good knowledge of the environment where this robot is intended to navigate, and terrain-related challenges are minimal. Our primary concern is obstacle avoidance, especially moving obstacles like people.
Currently, we’ve managed to make the robot avoid obstacles effectively. We are using Nav2 with its basic functionalities for navigation, along with custom code to filter out ground points so they are not treated as obstacles. All 3D points captured are projected onto a 2D costmap, and so far, this setup has been working well for navigation.
However, another issue has arisen: the robot's localization depends on the same 2D Lidar. In open areas, the robot starts drifting significantly, losing track of its exact position. I’ve tried several approaches to address this localization drift, but none have been satisfactory so far.
I would appreciate suggestions or ideas to improve the robot's localization in these scenarios.
